# Android View inflating

Tags: android

HI am creating view and added to the linearlayout, when i clicked an item in the row ,i need to know which row am clicked ,how can i done this ?

Am trying to listener for a textview in the row ,when the row clicked i need to know which row am clicked. NB SetonItemClickListener is not applicable to textview

Comment: I am also interested in the Answer to this question.

Comment: @Sheikh Aman i have no listview object , i just create the view and add the view to a linearlayout, it  have no setonitemclicklistener

Answer (score 0):

You need to set an OnItemClickListener. This tutorial describes it well:
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-listview.html

Comment: i have no listview object , i create one linearlayout and added the view to this linearlayout.

Comment: At the beginning of your post you say "HI am creating an listivew using view Inflation". If you do not use a ListView please edit your original problem description so we can understand what you mean.